# Swiper JS - show part of next slide

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I want to show a part of the second slide into view. Around 20-30%.
I have set slidesPerView to 2.1 (on mobile devices!) to show part of the next slide.
However, when scrolling through the slides it does not snap to the start of the container which results in parts of slides not within the view when scrolling through the swiper.

I've tried setting the height of the slide at 70% but this gives the same issue. I've also been fiddling with the slidesOffsetAfter parameter but no luck.

- Slide show snap to start of the container showing the whole image
- Next slide should be partially visible

To see the current state of the project: [live dev environment](https://js-dev1-1.webflow.io/)

You can see the issue on desktop in horizontal swiper and on tablet view in the vertical swiper.

**CSS**

```
<!-- swiper CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">

<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 1079px){
.swiper-section {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-top: 194px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px){
.main-navigation {
  left: 45px;
  top: 45px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px){
.sub-navigation {
  right: 45px;
  top: 45px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px){
.swiper-container {
    height: 965px;
}
}

.swiper-slide {
padding-bottom: 45px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
.swiper-slide {
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(even) {
 height: 75%;
 width: 45vw !important;
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(odd) {
 height: 100%;
  width: 55vw !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
.swiper-div {
margin: 0px 45px 0px 45px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
.swiper-slide:nth-child(even) {
     height: 100%!important;
     width: 100% !important;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
.swiper-slide:nth-child(odd) {
 height: 100%!important;
 width: 100% !important;
}
}


.swiper-slide>img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  width: 175px;
  margin-left: 65px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  }

.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  margin-top: 733px;
  background: #bababa;
}

.swiper-pagination-progressbar .swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill {
background: #888888;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
height: 12px;
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
display: none;
}

</style>
```

**JS**

```
<!-- swiper JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Swiper - Extra Step - add arrows and pagination html markup by code (Append) -->
<script>
  var swiperNodes = "";
  var pagination = '<div class=swiper-pagination></div>';
  var next_prev_buttons = '<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div><div class="swiper-button-next"></div>'; 
  var scrollbar = '<div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>';
  var swiperNodes = swiperNodes.concat(pagination, next_prev_buttons);
  /* loop throw all swipers on the page */
  $('.swiper-container').each(function( index ) {
    $( this ).append(swiperNodes);
  });
</script>
<!-- swiper JS Initialize -->
<script>
  var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    freeMode: false,
    loop: true,
    centeredSlides: false,
    // Enable lazy loading
    lazy: true,
     mousewheel: {
    invert: true,
    },
    keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
    onlyInViewport: false,
    },
    scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    draggable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'progressbar',
    },
    keyboard: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    breakpoints: {
      0: { /* when window >=0px - webflow mobile landscape/portriat */
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesOffsetBefore: 0,
        direction: 'vertical',
      },
      767: { /* when window >= 767px - webflow tablet */
        slidesPerView: 2.1,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        slidesOffsetBefore: 0,
        direction: 'vertical',
      },
      1279: { /* when window >= 988px - webflow desktop */
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 20,
        slidesOffsetBefore: 0,
      }
    },
    /* uncomment if you want autoplay slider
    autoplay: {
      delay: 3000,
    },
    */
    /* uncomment if you want scrollbar
     scrollbar: {
        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        hide: true,
      },
    */
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Follow this example (set width to auto and slide to 80% for example - do not use 2.1): https://swiperjs.com/demos/#auto_slides_per_view_carousel_mode

Answer (score 15):

you can change `slidesPerView` to float number for example 1.5 and if you set optional parameter to `centeredSlides: true,loop: true`you can see little of both prev and next slider

Comment: I have been using swiper for years but I have never thought that it is possible to simply use float number. Thank You, Sir!

Comment: Amazing, never contemplated using a decimal.

Comment: Even chatGPT failed to mention this

Answer (score 4):

This one will show a partial view of the next and previous slide. In my case it's a full width carousel so I'm using `vw` in the CSS, but you can use pixels or %

```
const swiper = new Swiper( selector, {
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            centeredSlides: true,
            loop: true,
            slidesPerGroup: 1,
            paginationClickable: true,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true,
            },
        } );
```

And the CSS:

```
.swiper-slide {
    width: 80vw;
  }
```

Comment: If I want to show the second slide with show slide 1 and 3 show a few parts. How do that?

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to show a part of the next slide only and both creating a `div` outside the `div.swiper-container` and style the inner `div` with `padding`, which can create the wanted effect.

If you only want to show the preview of the next, style only the padding-right or padding-left and you should be good to go.

The padding applied should consider the spaces between the containers. In my case the `spaceBetween` was 10, so I used 20px as padding.

Here's some pseudo code:

```html
<script>
const swiper = new Swiper( '.my-class', {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            slidesPerGroup: 2,
            centeredSlides: false,
            loop: true,
            paginationClickable: true,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true,
            },
        } );
</script>

<style>
.full-width {
    margin: 0 calc(-100vw / 2 + 100% / 2) !important;
    width: 100vw;
}

.my-class {
   padding: 20px;
}
</style>

<div class="full-width">
  <div class="swiper-container my-class">
    ...
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show 1 Slide Full and 2nd slide half you can use the config like

slidesPerView: 1.2, Working in swiper version 8.3

Answer (score 0):

here is my experience:
i want 5 slide items,
the start item and end item show perfect half size.

> $_offset_x: half size of each item, i use percentage according to the design.

```css
.swiper-wrapper {
    // left: $_offset_x!important;
    left: 9.63%!important;
}
```

use media query if you have addtional need for mobile.